# Dynamic variables for template are not loaded (in c# dotnet with blazor)

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to integrate our Blazor app with SendGrid.  I have added a controller in the API to accept the message information and pass it on to the SendGrid API.  It works fine for creating emails on the fly but is not working with email templates.

It seems that the dynamic template data is not being correctly loaded into the API object by the built-in routines in the SendGrid package for C#.  In the Blazor app, the dynamic variables are loaded into a object of type "dynamic" within a notification object as shown below.  The notification object is then passed to the API.

```
    {
        public ApiExternalNotificationEmailAddress FromAddress { get; set; }
        public List<ApiExternalNotificationEmailAddress> ToAddresses { get; set; }
        public List<ApiExternalNotificationEmailAddress>? CcAddresses { get; set; }
        public List<ApiExternalNotificationEmailAddress>? BccAddresses { get; set; }
        public string? Subject { get; set; }
        public string? Body { get; set; }
        public string? TemplateId { get; set; }
        public dynamic? Parameters { get; set; }
        public List<ApiExternalNotificationAttachment>? Attachments { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    {
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string? DisplayName { get; set; }

        public ApiExternalNotificationEmailAddress(string emailAddress, string? displayName = null)
        {
            EmailAddress = emailAddress;
            DisplayName = displayName;
        }
    }

            ApiExternalNotification notification2 = new()
                {
                    FromAddress = new ApiExternalNotificationEmailAddress("questions@signaturechampions.com", "Signature Championship Rings"),
                    ToAddresses = new List<ApiExternalNotificationEmailAddress>()
                    {
                        new ApiExternalNotificationEmailAddress("mwever@signaturechampions.com")
                    },
                    CcAddresses = null,
                    BccAddresses = null,
                    Subject = null,
                    TemplateId = "<snip>",
                    Parameters = new
                    {
                        coachName = order.Customer.FirstName,
                        repName = order.CreatedByUserName,
                        repEmail = createdBy.Email,
                        teamRoster = finalRosterFile.ViewUrl
                    }
                };
```

The controller then passes the information to the SendGrid API using the SetTemplateData() method.  (The rest of the data such as email addresses and subject are built as well but that code is not included.)

```
                message.SetTemplateData(notification.Parameters);
                var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(message);
```

When done this way, if I dump the message object I see that it included an object called "Personalizations.DynamicData".  And the resulting call to the SendGrid API returns a successful response but does not have any of the dynamic data filled in on the template.

I noticed that in examples of low-level calls to the API, it shows an object called "dynamic_template_data".  So I tried building my own copy of the SendGridMessage and Personalization classes where the dynamic data is renamed to "Dynamic_Template_Data" and sending that to the API through an HTTP request rather than than the SendEmailAsync() method.  When I did that, the email is generated with the dynamic data filled in.

```
        {
            public EmailAddress From { get; set; }
            public string Subject { get; set; }
            public List<DynamicSendGridPersonalization>? Personalizations { get; set; }
            public List<Content>? Contents { get; set; }
            public string? Plain_Text_Content { get; set; }
            public string? HtmlContent { get; set; }
            public List<Attachment>? Attachments { get; set; }
            public string? Template_Id { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string>? Headers { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string>? Sections { get; set; }
            public List<string>? Categories { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string>? CustomArgs { get; set; }
            public long? SendAt { get; set; }
            public ASM? Asm { get; set; }
            public string? Batch_Id { get; set; }
            public string? Ip_Pool_Name { get; set; }
            public MailSettings? Mail_Settings { get; set; }
            public TrackingSettings? Tracking_Settings { get; set; }
            public EmailAddress? Reply_To { get; set; }
            public List<EmailAddress>? Reply_Tos { get; set; }
        }

        private class DynamicSendGridPersonalization
        {
            public List<EmailAddress>? To { get; set; }
            public List<EmailAddress>? Cc { get; set; }
            public List<EmailAddress>? Bcc { get; set; }
            public List<EmailAddress>? From { get; set; }
            public string? Subject { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string>? Headers { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string>? Substitutions { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string>? CustomArgs { get; set; }
            public long? SendAt { get; set; }
            public dynamic? Dynamic_Template_Data { get; set; }
        }
```

```
                {
                    From = message.From,
                    Personalizations = new List<DynamicSendGridPersonalization>()
                    {
                        new DynamicSendGridPersonalization()
                        {
                            To = to,
                            Dynamic_Template_Data = notification.Parameters
                        }
                    },
                    Template_Id = notification.TemplateId,
                };
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {apiKey}");
                var myResponse = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send", myrequest);

                return myResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode;
```

It looks to me like there is something misnamed in the C# package.  But if I am just doing something wrong in the way I am using it, I'd be happy to correct it and use the package as it is rather than my workaround.

Comment: What happens when you use type of `object?` instead of `dynamic?`?
I have successfully used the `DynamicTemplateData` property on the personalization object, when using anonymous objects.

Comment: I get the same results when using object.

Comment: The SDK uses `Newtonsoft.Json` for serialization and deserialization, I wonder if maybe the library behaves differently under Blazor. Is this Blazor WASM or Blazor Server?
Can you reproduce this issue in a console application?